# Detect successful facebook post using FBDialogs

Tags: ios, facebook

I'm trying to present the facebook share dialog from my iOS app.

This code opens the facebook app and shows the dialog:

```
FBShareDialogParams* params = [[FBShareDialogParams alloc] init];
params.link = urlToShare;
params.name = @"Test";
params.description = @"Description";
params.picture = [NSURL URLWithString:FB_IMG_URL];

BOOL canPresentShareDialog = [FBDialogs canPresentShareDialogWithParams:params];
if (canPresentShareDialog) {
    [FBDialogs presentShareDialogWithParams:params clientState:nil handler:^(FBAppCall *call, NSDictionary *results, NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
            if ([FBErrorUtility shouldNotifyUserForError:error]) {
                UIAlertView* alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Facebook-Error!" message:[FBErrorUtility userMessageForError:error] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
                [alert show];
            }
        } else {
            NSLog(@"SUCCESS");
        }
    }];
}
```

In the completion handler I want to know if the user canceled the action. The results dictionary should tell me that. However I only get `didComplete=YES` in the dictionary but not a `completionGesture`. The `NSError` object is always `nil`.

The results dictionary is explained here: https://developers.facebook.com/ios/share-dialog/

So the problem is I can't tell if the post was successful or not.

Is something wrong with my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in the doc, the "completionGesture" field is "only available if the user logged into your app".

So if the user has never used Facebook login with your app before, you will not get that field, and will only see the "didComplete" field.

Answer (score 2):

If I am not wrong then you want to know if user is unable to post the data on facebook because of some error or because he pressed cancel button. If this is the case then use the code given below

```
 [FBDialogs presentShareDialogWithParams:shareParams
                              clientState:nil
                                  handler:^(FBAppCall *call, NSDictionary *results, NSError *error) {
           if(error) {
              NSLog(@"Error publishing story.");
           } else if (results[@"completionGesture"] && [results[@"completionGesture"] isEqualToString:@"cancel"]) {
              NSLog(@"User canceled story publishing.");
           } else {
              NSLog(@"Story published.");
           }
          }];
```

its been taken from [Facebook Developer Reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/ios-sdk-games/feed/). Let me know if it helps. Thanks

Comment: Thank you, that SHOULD work, but I don't get "completionGesture" in the results dict. I guess it is a bug in the Facebook SDK.

Comment: @phix23: please check a new Facebook SDK is available. It might be solved.

Comment: the problem still occurs in SDK version 3.7